# Infinite product $ \prod^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{3n}}-\frac{1}{2^{6n}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinite-product

> Find the value of the following expression  $$ \prod^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{3n}}-\frac{1}{2^{6n}}\right)$$

What I tried:

If $\frac{1}{2^3}=x$, then we can write expression as

$$\prod^{\infty}_{n=0}(1-x^n-x^{2n})=(1-1+1)(1-x-x^2)(1-x^2-x^4)(1-x^3-x^6)\cdots$$

How do I find that infinite product?

Comment: Please, do not do that !

Comment: @Claudi there is a mistake of $+$ sign and i edited it. But jam told me that this is not good. You will have to post it as new problem instead of change it. So i have posted it as new problem

Comment: I already made the second answer. It is the same principle in both cases. Try to make it it changing $2$ to $3$ and the exponents to whatever you want. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

*This was for the first version of the question.*
$$\prod^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{3n}}-\frac{1}{2^{6n}}\right)=\prod^{2}_{n=0}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{3n}}-\frac{1}{2^{6n}}\right)\prod^{\infty}_{n=3}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{3n}}-\frac{1}{2^{6n}}\right)$$

The first product is $-\frac{221705}{262144}$. For the second one, define
$$a_n=\left(1-x^n-x^{2n}\right)\implies \log(a_n)=\log\left(1-x^n-x^{2n}\right)$$ Now, using Taylor
$$\log(a_n)\sim -x^n-x^{2n}\implies \sum_{n=3}^\infty \log(a_n)\sim\frac{x^6+x^4+x^3}{(x-1) (x+1)}$$ Make $x=\frac 18$ to get 
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \log(a_n)\sim -\frac{577}{258048}\implies \prod^{\infty}_{n=3}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{3n}}-\frac{1}{2^{6n}}\right)\sim \exp{\left(-\frac{577}{258048} \right)}$$ So, an *estimate*  of the infinite product is
$$-\frac{221705}{262144}\exp{\left(-\frac{577}{258048} \right)}\approx -0.8438484857$$ while the "exact" value is                                            $-0.8438468422$

**Edit**

For the new version of the problem, the first product is $\frac{229881}{262144}$
$$\log(a_n)\sim -x^n+x^{2n}\implies \sum_{n=3}^\infty \log(a_n)\sim\frac{-x^6+x^4+x^3}{(x-1) (x+1)}$$
Make $x=\frac 18$ to get 
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \log(a_n)\sim -\frac{575}{258048}\implies \prod^{\infty}_{n=3}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{3n}}+\frac{1}{2^{6n}}\right)\sim \exp{\left(-\frac{575}{258048} \right)}$$ and the estimate becomes
$$\frac{229881}{262144}\exp{\left(-\frac{575}{258048} \right)}\approx  0.8749745708$$while the "exact" value is                                            $0.8749728798$

Comment: i have edited my problem. There is a plus sign instead of $-$

Comment: @jacky It is impolite to change a question once you've uploaded it. The correct thing to do is to post a new question.

Comment: Ok @Jam thanks so much